# checks both word with dash and underscore (-/_)

Tags: bash, if-statement, sed, while-loop, grep

Our server names either have a dash `(-)` or underscore `(_)`

file.txt consists of:

```
irl-iv-host01
irl-vm-host02
irl-rv-host01
irl-sd-host01
```

Objective is to check if the server exists and then run the next command.

So this command right here is where we check if the server exist on the list of zones.

```
var1=`ssh support@1.2.3.4 cfgactvshow | grep -i "$host" | awk '{print $2}'`
```

However, there are instances that the host configured on the list of zones are different, sometimes its `irl-iv-host01` or `irl_iv_host01` or `irl-iv_host01` or even `irl_iv-host01`

so what i want is to check if host `irl-iv-host01` is on the list of zones whether it's name is any of these `irl-iv-host01`, `irl_vm_host01`, `irl-iv_host01`, `irl_iv-host01`

and then use it for another command that checks the zonename which is

```
ssh support@1.2.3.4 zoneshow "$var1"
```

Now, if in the event that during the `grep` process the result is multiple, i guess or maybe it will be stored to another variable which we can also use like the sample below.

Example if multiple output:

```
ssh support@1.2.3.4 cfgactvshow | grep -i "$host" | awk '{print $2}'
zone1_irl-iv-host01
zone2_irl-iv-host01
zone3_irl-iv-host01

ssh support@1.2.3.4 zoneshow zone1_irl-iv-host01
ssh support@1.2.3.4 zoneshow zone2_irl-iv-host01
ssh support@1.2.3.4 zoneshow zone3_irl-iv-host01
```

The question is, is there a simpler way to do it?

I just feel i'm running around the bush

```
while read -r host;
        do
        withunderscore=`echo $host | sed 's/-/_/g'`
        var1=`ssh support@1.2.3.4 command | grep "$host"`
        var2=`ssh support@1.2.3.4 command | grep "$withunderscore"`
        
        if var1 is not empty then run the command but if it is, test var2. 
        If var2 is not empty then run the command but if it is, echo "both vars are empty.

done < file.txt
```

I would appreciate any help. thank you.

Comment: Has anyone considered not using such a haphazard naming system for the servers?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```bash
# grab output of ssh support@1.2.3.4 cfgactvshow only once
hostdata="$(ssh support@1.2.3.4 cfgactvshow)"

while read -r host; do
   echo "processing host: $host"

   grep -F "${host//_/-}" <<< "$hostdata" | while read -r var; do
      # run ssh check
      ssh support@1.2.3.4 zoneshow "$var"
   done

done < file.txt
```

What it does:

1. Runs `${host//_/-}` to replace all `_` with `-` before running `grep -F` with `$host` (variable with all hyphens only)
2. Uses output of first ssh command
3. Loops through output of `cfgactvshow` command to run next `zoneshow` command

Comment: actually the host should be searched first with the command `cfgactvshow` before `zoneshow` because zoneshow will be using the output of `cfgactvshow` if host is found

Comment: That's what this script is doing. It runs `tr | grep` in the output of `cfgactvshow` and then runs `zoneshow` for each entry.

Comment: seems like it's not working

**testcheck.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `<'**
**testcheck.sh: line 10: `       done < <(tr '_' '-' <<< "$zonedata" | grep -F "$host")'**

Comment: This requires `bash`. Please make sure you are not using any other shell

Comment: I have removed process substitution, try it now

Comment: It still fails. However, I had it work. It sounds clever though. :)

Did this
`var=$(echo host$ | sed 's/[-|_]/[-_]/g'`
`ssh support@1.2..3.4 cfgactvshow | grep "$var"`

so it went like this;
`irl[-_]iv[-_]host01`

Comment: `It still fails`: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: There's no output.

actually, the main goal really to is match the hostname. So in really it's like this ` `cmd=cfgactvshow | grep  irl[-_]iv[-_]host01` and when you have the `$cmd` that when you're going to use it for `zoneshow $cmd`

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash`? Can you tell output of `echo $BASH_VERSION` ?

Comment: I am **4.2.46(2)-release**

Comment: ok, please run your script with `bash -x script.sh` (with the code I have suggested) and paste output in question. There might be some unexpected characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `-` and `_` to regex `[-_]`:

```
while read -r host; do
    var=$(ssh support@1.2.3.4 command | grep -E "${host//[-_]/\[_-\]}")
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file.txt | tr '_' '-' > f2
mv f2 file.txt
```

That will change all of the underscores to hyphens.

```
while read -r host;
    do
    ssh support@1.2.3.4 cfgactvshow | grep -i "$host" | awk '{print $2}'
    done < file.txt
```